Am I suppose to correct non Muslims backbiting behavior or just stay silent?
Asalam alaikum! Hope everyone is well today inshallah. So I live at a group home and I'm surround by gossip and backbiting all day am I supposed to correct other non Muslims about what there doing ???

Allah(swt) made us(Muslims) examples for humankind, and He(swt) tells us what to say and how to say it. If you have the chance to say,in a beautiful way, that talking behind each other's back is equivalent to eating each other's flesh then you should do so. And always have back up. Not only for fights but to back what you say. May Allah(swt) make it easy for you in there. I know your struggle, beloved. As Salaam alayka wa Rahmantulahi. Sura 49 tells us what to say

Different cultures and religions have different social norms and expectations.
Attempting to correct someone's behavior based on your own
cultural standards can be seen as disrespectful or intrusive.
If the person is a close friend or family member,
you might consider having a private conversation
with them to express your concerns. However, it's important
to approach the conversation with empathy and respect.
If the behavior is causing harm or disrupting your community,
you might consider addressing it in a respectful and diplomatic manner.
Ultimately, the decision of whether or not to correct someone's behavior is a personal one.
It's important to consider the potential consequences of your actions and
choose the approach that you believe is most appropriate.
